# Unable to download xlsx from web service

Tags: java, web-services, download, resteasy, xssf

I am trying to download xlsx file generated using Apache XSSF from RESTEasy based web service.

I can download the file but when double clicked to open, it says file can not be openend:

[image]

Below is the source code:

**Web service controller:**

```
@GET
@Path(/download)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
public Response downloadFile() {

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = myService.processGbiValidationExceptions();

    ResponseBuilder response = Response.ok((Object) baos.toByteArray());
    response.header("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=My_File.xlsx");
    return response.build();
}
```

**Service:**

```
public ByteArrayOutputStream processGbiValidationExceptions() {
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();

    // code to write to workbook


    // Create stream
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        workbook.write(baos);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Error occurred while writing workbook to stream", e);
        throw new IptException(e);
    }

    return baos;
}
```

Any clues what I am doing incorrect over here? Thanks

P.S.: I am on Mac!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were few problems with my client side code which I used previously to download the file. Now, I am using [download.js](http://danml.com/download.html) and it works.

Below is the code:

```
 import download from 'downloadjs';    
    .
    .
    .
    fetch(FETCH_URL, {
      method: 'GET',
      dataType: 'json',
      credentials: 'include'
    }).then(response => {
        if(response.status === 200) {
            return response.blob();
        }
      }, () => {
        // when error do something
      }
    ).then(
      // Following line helps download
      blob => download(blob, "someexcel.xlsx", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")
    )
```

Also, the MIME type needs to be set to `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet` in order to download `xlsx` file:

```
@Produces("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")
```

Cheers